# Marshaling a c char array[128] to c#

Tags: c#, dll, struct, interop, marshalling

Simple question, but I can't find a straight answer: I want to have a char array of 128 bytes in my C structure. I am running this under 64bit Windows.  I want to marshal this over to c#, using the following:

The C code:

```
typedef struct s_parameterStuct
{
    int count;
    char name[ 128 ];
} parameterStruct;
```

And the c# code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public class parameterStuct
{
    public int count;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 128)]
    public char[] name;
}
```

Since a char is 2 bytes in c#, should the SizeConst be 128 or 256.  Both seem to work fine, but I know only one of them is correct.

Comment: You could just use a byte array, right?

Comment: @Wug, New to C#, so didn't think about that.  So I could just always use "char []" on the C side, and "byte []" on c#.  Good.  But, just for the sake of completeness, which is correct: sizeConst=128 or 256 if I stuck with char on both sides?

Comment: Neither.  It's probably 64.  That said, you shouldn't mix data types of different sizes (especially if you have to ask)

Comment: @Wug, By "I shouldn't mix data types" do you mean I shouldn't use char on c and char on c# side (because that is mixed), whereas char on C side and byte on c# side is unmixed?

Comment: by data types, I meant data types of different sizes.  They're both called `char`, but one is 1 byte and the other is 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size would be 64, since 64 2-byte quantities have the same size as 128 1-byte ones.

I'd use a byte array for marshaling because otherwise you'll have to put up with splitting values in order to get the C chars (which are single bytes).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to marshal to a C# char array (not sure why you would want to) then the size would be set to 64 on the C# end.

However, you should be marshaling to a byte array (size 128) and then converting the byte array to a .net string (assuming you want a string) using the appropriate Text.Encoding call.